# Omit a tag in a template but display the children anyway

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my angular template, I'm trying to do this :

```
<div id="maybe">
  <p>Some text</p>
<div>
```

I want to omit the div `maybe` based on a variable, but I still want to display the `<p>` anyway.

For the moment, I'm coding this :

```
<div *ngIf="displayed" id="maybe">
  <p>Some text</p>
<div>
<p *ngIf="!displayed">Some text</p>
```

But by doing this, I must copy/paste the `<p>` twice.

Is there a way in angular to do this? Something like an `*ngOmit="displayed"`?

Comment: You could make a reusable angular component that has the same logic in the template that you've written for optionally showing the parent div. To achieve code reuse of the <p> tag, you would make the component accept an input parameter template, eg. `<p>Some text</p>`. Here is a good tutorial on creating reusable components: https://www.ifourtechnolab.com/blog/creating-reusable-angular-components